# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedAlertOpenError:

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails

I get an error because an alert is open. And I think I handle it in the right way ;-)
According to my research the 'accept_confirm' block is the way to handle this.

```
feature "Users can delete studynotes", js: true do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:otheruser) { create(:user) }

  before { create(:studynote, title: "Jona", author: user) }

  scenario "successfully", js:true do
    login_as(user)

    visit studynotes_path
    click_link "Jona"

    accept_confirm do
      click_link t(:delete_item, item: Studynote.model_name.human)
    end

    expect(page).to have_content(t("activerecord.messages.deleted", model: "bijbelstudie"))
    expect(page).to have_current_path pericopes_path
    expect(page).to have_no_content "Jona"
  end
```

This is the error I get

1. Users can delete studynotes successfully
   Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content(t("activerecord.messages.deleted", model: "bijbelstudie"))

   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedAlertOpenError:
   unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Weet u zeker dat u deze bijbelstudie wilt verwijderen?}
   (Session info: headless chrome=119.0.6045.159)

   ```
     # 0   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a2dd28 chromedriver + 4795688
       # 1   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a252b3 chromedriver + 4760243
       # 2   chromedriver                        0x00000001045fe88d chromedriver + 407693
       # 3   chromedriver                        0x000000010460c2c6 chromedriver + 463558
       # 4   chromedriver                        0x000000010461208b chromedriver + 487563
       # 5   chromedriver                        0x00000001045e3920 chromedriver + 297248
       # 6   chromedriver                        0x000000010460bd32 chromedriver + 462130
       # 7   chromedriver                        0x0000000104690a51 chromedriver + 1006161
       # 8   chromedriver                        0x0000000104674a73 chromedriver + 891507
       # 9   chromedriver                        0x000000010463f143 chromedriver + 672067
       # 10  chromedriver                        0x000000010464031e chromedriver + 676638
       # 11  chromedriver                        0x00000001049ee795 chromedriver + 4536213
       # 12  chromedriver                        0x00000001049f3853 chromedriver + 4556883
       # 13  chromedriver                        0x00000001049d4001 chromedriver + 4427777
       # 14  chromedriver                        0x00000001049f459d chromedriver + 4560285
       # 15  chromedriver                        0x00000001049c548c chromedriver + 4367500
       # 16  chromedriver                        0x0000000104a140e8 chromedriver + 4690152
       # 17  chromedriver                        0x0000000104a1429e chromedriver + 4690590
       # 18  chromedriver                        0x0000000104a24eee chromedriver + 4759278
       # 19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8036f5202 _pthread_start + 99
       # 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8036f0bab thread_start + 15
       #
   ```

```
./spec/features/study_notes/deleting_studynotes_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 8.38 seconds (files took 5.32 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Comment: Which line do you get the error from?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for helping! I've added the complete error to the question

Comment: So the test fails on the first assert. Which makes sense to me, that assert must fail because apparently the confirmation box is still open

Comment: And you’re sure it doesn’t do a double confirmation of delete?

Comment: It does so indeed. I just checked at the site. No idea why it does that, but I'm gonna find out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone runs into the same problem, here's how I fixed this.
I noticed in the page source that all my javascript files were loaded twice. After removing these 2 lines from my application.html.haml, that problem was solved.

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```